# Animate drawing of path on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, konvajs

My problem is how to animate the drawing of a path between two points.

Consider a curved line or path between two points, A & B. I can draw this easily on the canvas using the line drawing functions in Konvajs.

However, what I actually want is to animate the revealing of the line so that it starts from point A and progressively draws to point B. The reveal should be animated so I can apply pleasing easings.

As a comparable example, see the brief video on this site https://coggle.it/ where the video shows the creation of a new box and the line draws to connect it to the old.

Comment: Welcome - I can see that you have tried to explain what you need help with and I am sorry but I don't quite understand what you are after. StackOverflow is a problem solving site so you need to write a precise problem you need solved. If you need general knowledge then fire up Google. Can you explain more about what you need please ?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat I need to make line with animation like on this site https://coggle.it/, so then you press add button, the line will appear with an animation

Comment: Hi - I edited your question so that it is easier to understand in the context of Konvajs. Also, please learn from this style of how to pose a question on SO. You could improve the question much more and solicit a faster answer if you include a small amount of code that shows what you have tried. Even better, add a working snippet which is a bit of JS that works right here in the page on SO - see other questions for Konvajs which include snippets as examples that you can cut & paste.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Ok! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a potential answer (special thanks to [@markov00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/408727/markov00) re same technique in SVG). It works by manipulating the path dashOffset and dash attributes. There is an excellent explanation of the technique [here in a post by Jake Archibald](https://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/) which also includes an interactive experiment with sliders which I found very useful.

I have tried to make the demo as lightweight as possible and just show the technique - though I added a slider and some UI to help understand the process. The use of jquery is only for the UI parts which are not needed for the technique.

Couple of points:

- The demo here uses a path from 3 straight line segments. But I tried curves and combination paths and the technique works in those cases too - so any path should work.
- I found that using a close-path command (z) on the path caused the path length function to be short on the true distance. This appears as an amount of the path  remaining stroked or gapped at either end, with the size depending on the jump between first & last to close the path.
- The path length is virtually always going to be decimal so don't try to do everything as integers as you will ultimately find your stroke is slightly overlong or short.

To adopt this for animation and easing etc, take the couple of lines from the slider change event and stick them inside the frame callback, manipulating the maths to suit your case.

```js
// Set up the canvas / stage
var stage = new Konva.Stage({container: 'container1', width: 320, height: 180});

// Add a layer
var layer = new Konva.Layer({draggable: false});
stage.add(layer);

// show where the start of the path is.
var circle = new Konva.Circle({
  x: 66,
  y: 15,
  radius: 5,
  stroke: 'red'
 })
 layer.add(circle);

// draw a path.
    var path = new Konva.Path({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      data: 'M66 15 L75 100 L225 120 L100 17 L66 15',
      stroke: 'green'
    });

// get the path length and set this as the dash and dashOffset. 
var pathLen = path.getLength();
path.dashOffset(pathLen);
path.dash([pathLen]);

layer.add(path)
stage.draw();

// Some UI bits
$('#dist').attr('max', parseInt(pathLen)); // set slider max to length of path
$('#pathLen').html('Path : ' + pathLen); // display path length

// jquery event listener on slider change
$('#dist').on('input', function(){

  // compute the new dash lenth as original path length - current slider value. 
  // Means that dashLen initially = path len and moves toward zero as slider val increases.
  var dashLen = pathLen - $(this).val();;
  path.dashOffset(dashLen);   // set new value
  layer.draw();               // refresh the layer to see effect

  // update the UI elements      
  $('#dashLen').html('Dash: ' + dashLen);
  $('#pathPC').html(parseInt(100-(100 * (dashLen/pathLen)), 10) + '%');

})
```

```css
.info 
{
padding-left: 20px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/2.5.1/konva.js"></script>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input class='slider' id='dist' type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange"/>
  <span class='info' id='pathPC'></span>
  <span class='info' id='pathLen'></span>
  <span class='info' id='dashLen'></span>
</div>
<div id='container1' style="display: inline-block; width: 300px, height: 200px; background-color: silver; overflow: hidden; position: relative;"></div>
<div id='img'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution with animation:

```js
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;

    // Set up the canvas / stage
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height
    });

    // Add a layer
    var layer = new Konva.Layer({
        draggable: false
    });
    stage.add(layer);

    // show where the start of the path is.
    var circle = new Konva.Circle({
        x: 66,
        y: 15,
        radius: 5,
        stroke: 'red'
    })
    layer.add(circle);

    // draw a path.
    var path = new Konva.Path({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        data: 'M66 15 L75 100 L225 120 L100 17 L66 15',
        stroke: 'green'
    });

    // get the path length and set this as the dash and dashOffset. 
    var pathLen = path.getLength();
    path.dashOffset(pathLen);
    path.dash([pathLen]);

    // make some animation with stop
    var anim = new Konva.Animation(function (frame) {
        var dashLen = pathLen - frame.time / 5;
        path.dashOffset(dashLen);
        if (dashLen < 0) {
            anim.stop();
        }
    }, layer);

    anim.start();

    layer.add(path)
    stage.draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/2.5.1/konva.js"></script>
<div id='container' style="display: inline-block; width: 300px, height: 200px; background-color: silver; overflow: hidden; position: relative;"></div>
<div id='img'></div>
```

Comment: Nice one - I switched your code into a snippet. Take note for your next post.

Answer (score 0):

And here is an alternative to @Roxane's animated version but using a tween.

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;

    // Set up the canvas / stage
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height
    });

    // Add a layer
    var layer = new Konva.Layer({
        draggable: false
    });
    stage.add(layer);

    // show where the start of the path is.
    var circle = new Konva.Circle({
        x: 66,
        y: 15,
        radius: 5,
        stroke: 'red'
    })
    layer.add(circle);

    // draw a path.
    var path = new Konva.Path({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        data: 'M66 15 L75 100 L225 120 L100 17 L66 15',
        stroke: 'green'
    });

    // get the path length and set this as the dash and dashOffset. 
    var pathLen = path.getLength();
    path.dashOffset(pathLen);
    path.dash([pathLen]);

    layer.add(path);  // have to add to layer for tweening.
    
    // create the tween
    var tween = new Konva.Tween({
        node: path,
        dashOffset: 0,
        easing: Konva.Easings['BounceEaseOut'],
        duration: 1.5
    });
     tween.play(); // execute the tween

    stage.draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/2.5.1/konva.js"></script>
<div id='container' style="display: inline-block; width: 300px, height: 200px; background-color: silver; overflow: hidden; position: relative;"></div>
<div id='img'></div>
```